# How do I find the EXEs and/or the DLLs of a Windows Store App?

Tags: dll, windows-store-apps, exe

How do I find the EXEs and DLLs of a Windows Store App? The target seems to be very odd in the shortcuts on the desktop, and I can't look at them more because these are virtual files. The target seems to be a package ID, followed by an exclamation point, followed by a keyword. Where can I find the files for these apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `%programfiles%`, make sure hidden folders are enabled, then try to access the `WindowsApps` folder. If it gives a pop up saying you don't have access, click the "Security" button then "Advanced" then change the owner to "Administrators" and click Apply and then just press okay on everything.